# Inefficient VBA: Adding columns with data running very slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I am running code that will insert columns into visible sheets based on the value of a cell on the main page.  If the individual inputs a 10, then 10 columns are inserted on the visible sheets and those inserted columns copy the data from the previous column.  This method works well, however, it will run rather slow at times and is almost unusable when you reach larger amounts of columns that need to be inserted.

I have it so that you can select only a few of the sheets you need, or sometimes just one sheet, and run the code so that it will work.  In those instances it can take up to 45 mins to complete.  It was over an hour, but I went through and switched the formulas over from vloopups to index/match.

I wasn't sure if there was anything I could do with the code to help speed things up, especially when a larger amount of columns are inserted.  On average there will be around 100 or less but it can get up to over 500.

This code goes into the sheet that determines the keycells range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
                                                                                                                                             
    Dim KeyCells As Range, colNum As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    
        SOMESHEETS = "*C-Proposal-19*MemberInfo-19*Schedule J-19*NOL-19*NOL-P-19*NOL-PA-19*Schedule R-19*Schedule A-3-19*Schedule A-19*Schedule H-19*"
        Set KeyCells = Range("B30")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
            If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
                colNum = KeyCells.Value
                If colNum > 0 Then
                 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                     If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                     If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=colNum
                     End If
                     End If
                 Next ws
                End If
            End If
        End If
        

    
    SOMESHEETS = "*MemberInfo-20*C-Proposal-20*Schedule J-20*NOL-20*Schedule R-20*NOL-P-20*SchA-3-20*Schedule H-20*NOL-PA-20*Schedule A-20*Schedule A-5-20*"
    Set KeyCells = Range("B36")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
            colNum = KeyCells.Value
            If colNum > 0 Then
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=colNum
                    End If
                    End If
                Next ws
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code that goes into a module

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub InsertColumnsOnSheet(ByVal argSheet As Worksheet, ByVal argColNum As Long)

    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim TotalCol As Long, LeftFixedCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("MemberInfo-20")
    With argSheet
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, .Columns.Count))
        Set c = Rng.Find("END")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            TotalCol = c.Column
            LeftFixedCol = 1
            If TotalCol < LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Then
                For i = TotalCol To LeftFixedCol + argColNum
                    .Columns(2).Copy
                    .Columns(3).Resize().Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Next i
                End If
            If TotalCol > LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Then
                For i = TotalCol - 1 To LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Step -1
                    .Columns(i).Delete
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

This portion is repeated for each sheet and changes depending on the column that is copied and where it will be inserted.

Comment: Whenever you insert or delete rows & columns, it is much faster if you can do them all at once.

Comment: You can avoid using the clipboard to copy and paste and instead just assign the values.

Comment: @Toddleson - How would you suggest inserting all the columns at one time?  I tried playing around with resize and adding `.Columns(7).Resize(, argColNum).Insert` but that was adding in an amount of columns that was not consistent with what was in the keycells range.  I also could not properly adjust the amount of columns needed.  If I start with 5 and need to add one, an employee with adjust the keycells to 6 and need it to add just one new column

Answer (score 0):

Add after the variables declarations the bellow code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

This will make your code faster because excel will not have to update visually the sheet.

Comment: Also worth mentioning `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`.  Whenever the script is making a lot of sheet changes, turning off sheet recalculations will stop Excel from wasting time re-checking every formula after each change. Don't forget to turn it back on at the end of the macro `xlCalculationAutomatic`!